# quickbook online export limit on line entries in journal entry

Tags: quickbooks-online

We are trying to export multiple accounts as Journal Entry to quickbook. For this each account is created as line item and added in Journal Entry. When we export the file we see there are many records not getting exported ( like 70 failed in 100). So we were wondering about any limit.
Is there any threshold of number of line entry to be added for a Journal Entry?

Actually prior to sending there was method call which will retrieve all accounts & validate the account if its present or not. It was failing there..QBO deosn't sends all accounts when ask for list of accounts & there is no documentation about the sharing the data.

Comment: How are you exporting the data?

Comment: We are calling through Java...Each account is added as line item & finally added in Journal Entry